# Downcast to Array and getting value on one line

Tags: swift

Suppose a mixed `Dictionary` of value type `Any`, holding an array as one of the values:

```
let myArray = ["A", "B", "C"]

var myDictionary:Dictionary<String, Any> = [
    "Array":myArray,
    "String":"A String"
]
```

To get the `String "B"`:

```
var downcastToArray:String[] = myDictionary["Array"] as String[]

downcastToArray[1] // Got the "B". Great
```

Can this be done without assigning a `var` first?

```
myDictionary["Array"] as String[] // I got the String[], now what?

myDictionary["Array"] as String[] [1] // Any way to get the [1] value ?

myDictionary["Array"]?[1] // Nop

myDictionary["Array"]![1] // Na..

myDictionary["Array"]![1] as String // No go..
```

Let me stop here and just mention that I have over 20 lines of similar 'brainstorming'. Or maybe I should treat my `dictionary`'s `Any` differently? (Any? Any! .. arrrr.. Any*%#$!^)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want it in one line:

```
(myDictionary["Array"] as [String])[1]
```

However, be sure you are very confident about the type being right as it will throw a runtime error and halt the whole program if it is not.

Comment: Thank you!!! (This is just for learning Swift purposes, I still work with Obj-C, so yes, of course I need to 'type-check').